# How to Add Specific word in a cell in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I need help i want to add "+"Sign to my ad the words in excel file . Please have a look for some keywords.

+yellow +diamond +new +york
+1 ct +yellow +diamond new +york

now see 2nd phrase is missing "+"Sign in some of the words .

I have around 10000 words in a doc and many of them missing "+" sign .

I do not know macros so if there is any other idea .. And if macro is only solution then please explain how to use that .

Thanks & Regards
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

Select all, HOME > Editing - Find & Select, Replace...,

Find what: (space) Replace with: (space)`+`, Replace All,

Find what: `++`, Replace with: `+`, Replace All.